# Handle exceptions in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to *handle* exceptions on the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException callback? 
I want to do the following:

- Show my own "an exception has
  occured" dialog, with a "Send Report"
  button
- After the user dismissed the
  box, I want to close my app, but I do
  not want to Windows default crash dialog "The
  application needs to close" box to
  show up.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could to use [`Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) method.

Please, take also a look here: [User Friendly Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Hope this link helps:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions

As the code shows, just listen to the exception and do what you want when it happens.